# iOS build is not showing in appstoreconnect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I submitted a build on iTunes connect twice via appstore & Application Loader. It is showing me progress while uploading in activity tab. But when the build is successfully uploaded, the build is not showing up in activity. I don't know what the reason is, but I can't see build.

Comment: And when i want to again upload build with same version it shows me error that Binary already exist.

Comment: Apple send me email about error. Finally i check the email and resolve errors and again upload then its fine now.